gforth: problem getting back values from the return stack
I was trying this binary to decimal conversion test for practice.
\ decimal to binary conversion

variable counts

: db-test  ( n1 -- b1 b2 b3 b4 ... )
  0 counts !
  begin
    dup
  while
    2 /mod \ swap >r 
    1 counts +!
  repeat
   \ counts 0 do r> loop
;

The above code works but the binary digits are in reverse order (13 is 1101):
13 db-test  ok
.s <5> 1 0 1 1 0  ok

In order to reverse the stack I thought of placing the remainders in the return stack.
When I take out the commented lines
variable counts

: db-test  ( n1 -- b1 b2 b3 b4 ... )
  0 counts !
  begin
    dup
  while
    2 /mod  swap >r 
    1 counts +!
  repeat
    counts 0 do r> loop
;

I get this:
13 db-test  ok
.s <5> 0 0 4517901033 2 2  ok

It looks like the loop in the last line is not getting back the remainders I sent to the return stack. And why do I see memory location instead of the value?
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT
I found a simpler way to reverse the stack:
depth 0 do >r r> . loop

So, this code now works:
: db-test  ( n1 -- b1 b2 b3 b4 ... )
  begin
    dup
  while
    2 /mod 
  repeat
  drop depth 0 do >r r> . loop
;


13 db-test 1 1 0 1  ok

